# Counting the number of radio buttons in a page using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am writing a script to count the number of radio buttons on the webpage - https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeI8_vYyaJgM7SJM4Y9AWfLq-tglWZh6yt7bEXEOJr_L-hV1A/viewform?formkey=dGx0b1ZrTnoyZDgtYXItMWVBdVlQQWc6MQ
But it always throws me an error
The common identifier between all the radio button is the role-radio.

```
<div class="appsMaterialWizToggleRadiogroupEl exportToggleEl isCheckedNext" jscontroller="D8e5bc" jsaction="keydown:I481le;dyRcpb:dyRcpb;click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue; focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef;touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc(preventMouseEvents=true|preventDefault=true); touchcancel:JMtRjd;" jsshadow="" aria-label="1" data-value="1" role="radio" aria-checked="false" aria-posinset="1" aria-setsize="5" tabindex="0"><div class="appsMaterialWizToggleRadiogroupInk exportInk"></div><div class="appsMaterialWizToggleRadiogroupInnerBox"></div><div class="appsMaterialWizToggleRadiogroupRadioButtonContainer"><div class="appsMaterialWizToggleRadiogroupOffRadio exportOuterCircle"><div class="appsMaterialWizToggleRadiogroupOnRadio exportInnerCircle"></div></div></div></div>
```

```
driver.get("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeI8_vYyaJgM7SJM4Y9AWfLq-tglWZh6yt7bEXEOJr_L-hV1A/viewform?formkey=dGx0b1ZrTnoyZDgtYXItMWVBdVlQQWc6MQ")

ele=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[role=radio]")

print(len(ele))
```

I am new to Selenium and this type of issues is really confusing. TIA

Comment: Do you want number of radio buttons or number of questions having radio button?

Comment: The number of radio buttons on that webpage

Answer (score 0):

try this selector

```
by_xpath("//div[@role='radio']")
by_css("div[role='radio']")
```

I recommend everybody to use CSS, supossedly is faster than xpath

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of radio buttons on the [webpage](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeI8_vYyaJgM7SJM4Y9AWfLq-tglWZh6yt7bEXEOJr_L-hV1A/viewform?formkey=dGx0b1ZrTnoyZDgtYXItMWVBdVlQQWc6MQ) you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `class_name`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeI8_vYyaJgM7SJM4Y9AWfLq-tglWZh6yt7bEXEOJr_L-hV1A/viewform?formkey=dGx0b1ZrTnoyZDgtYXItMWVBdVlQQWc6MQ")
  print(len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("appsMaterialWizToggleRadiogroupOffRadio")))
  ```
- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeI8_vYyaJgM7SJM4Y9AWfLq-tglWZh6yt7bEXEOJr_L-hV1A/viewform?formkey=dGx0b1ZrTnoyZDgtYXItMWVBdVlQQWc6MQ")
  print(len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.appsMaterialWizToggleRadiogroupOffRadio")))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  48
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try any of this:

```
print(len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("exportOuterCircle")))
print(len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("exportInnerCircle")))
```

These will output:

```
48
48
```

You can try other css selector as well. The idea is to inspect element and find a unique class which is being used only for radio button and use that class in css selector. It will give you list of elements. You can then get the count of that list.